# Evaluating expressions with operators

Tags: c, algorithm

First, I know I know. This question has kind of been asked some times before, but most of the answers got on other topics only partly answer my question.

I'm doing something which can parse C like expressions.
That includes expressions for example like (some examples)

```
1) struct1.struct2.structarray[283].shd->_var
2) *((*array_dptr)[2][1] + 5)
3) struct1.struct2.struct3.var + b * c / 3 % 5
```

Problem is... I need to be fast on this. The fastest possible, even if it makes the code ugly - well, obviously, the speed improvement must be tangible. The reason is that it is interpreted. It needs to be fast...

I have many questions, and I will probably ask some more depending on your answers. But anyways...

First, I'm aware of "operator priorities". For example algorithms implemented in C compilers will assign to operators a priority number and evaluate the expression based on that.
I've consulted this table : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence

Now, this is cool but... I wonder a few things.
My principal question is... how would you implement this to be the fastest possible?

I have thought about for example... (please note the program I'm speaking about actually parses a file containing these expressions, and *not* all C operators will be supported)

1) Stocking the expression string into an array, storing each operator position inside an array, and then starting to parse all this crap, starting from the highest priority operator. For example if I had str = "2*1+3", then after checking all the operators present, I would check for the position at str[1], and the check at right and left, do the operation (here multiply) and then substitude the expression with the result and evaluate again.

The problem I see there is... say two operators in the expr are the same priority

for example : var1 * var2 / var3 / var4

since * and / have both the same precedence, how to know on which position to start the parsing? Of course this example is rather intuitive, but I can the problem growing on enormous expressions.

2) Is this even possible to do it non recursive? Usually recursive means slower due to multiple function call setting their own stack frames, re-initializing stuff etc etc.

3) How to distinguish unary operators from non unaries?

For example : 2 + *a + b * c

There is the dereferencing op and the multiplication one. Intuitively I have an idea on how to do it, but I ain't sure. I'd rather have your advices on this (i think : check if one of the right or left members are operators, if so, then it's unary?)

4) I don't get expressions being evaluated right-to-left. Seems so unnatural to be. More that I don't unterstand what does it means. Would you show an example? Why do it that way?!?

5) Do you have better algorithms in head? Better ideas of achieving it?

For now, that sums pretty much what I'm thinking about.
This ain't an homework by the way. It's practical stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a standard parser generator, like lex and yacc, flex and bison, etc.? They solve problems like this easily.

Comment: Your question is essentially "how to parse expressions efficiently". The answer is: it's hard, don't try to re-invent an algorithm, there already are pretty good ones, such as the [top-down operator precedence parser](http://javascript.crockford.com/tdop/tdop.html). By the way: if you're interpreting stuff, don't worry about parsing/compilation time. You only need to parse once. Then whatever intermediate form (AST, bytecode, etc.) you generate, you can walk it faster. So it's not really the parser that is the bottleneck.

Comment: @ Barnar : I do not have a quick answer to this question. Probably my limited knowledge in the domain of parser generators. I will look into it indeed. But I still want to get to know how the algoritms work. Thanks for your suggestion though, you are right, I should give it a try.
@H2CO3 : Thanks for the link